# NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()Lscala/collection/GenTraversable

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am compiling my JAR file, but I am unable to run the JAR because the error in the title occurs.  I am using `sbt assembly` in order to compile, so that all dependencies are included.

Scala 2.11.12
Spark 2.4.2

```scala
package com.foo.bar

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import Array._

object DebugApp extends App {

  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        println("Must pass in args:  sparkMaster, dataPath")
    }
    val sparkMaster            = args(0)
    val bucket                 = args(1)
    val dataPath               = args(2)
    val parsedDestionationPath = args(3)
    val rawDestionationPath    = args(4)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4jspark.root.logger=WARN,console")
      .appName("Parser")
      .master(sparkMaster)
      .getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

The first 2 lines of the error show this is coming from Spark:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer$.empty()Lscala/collection/GenTraversable;
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:72)

Further context is the dependencies I am using in `build.sbt`:

```scala
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.12"
fork in run := true
...
val sparkV          = "2.4.2"
val spark          = "org.apache.spark"           %% "spark-core"              % sparkV
val sparkSql       = "org.apache.spark"           %% "spark-sql"               % sparkV
val sparkHive      = "org.apache.spark"           %% "spark-hive"              % sparkV
```

Comment: This problem looks like incompatible Scala library versions, but the dependencies you show shouldn't produce it. Do you have any other dependencies, especially without `%%`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, if you want to run Spark locally (v2.4.x), you must specify Hadoop as 2.6.5.  You can use *any* version of the AWS Java SDK, but Hadoop is specifically locked to that version.  If you wish to circumvent this, it would be wise to upload files to S3 in one of 2 ways:

- From your JAR, using `TransferManager`

  - With v1.11.600, there is a bug that is causing it to use `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient` 4.5.8, which can cause logs to flood
- From a bash script using `aws s3 sync` <-- **recommended**